# How can I get my passport back while my application for UK Permanent Residence is under process?

Tags: united-kingdom, eu-citizens

I submitted an application for UK Permanent Residence as a single EU citizen living and working in UK for more than 5 years. According to Royal Mail tracking, my application has been delivered to Home Office on 19/12/2016. The fee has been deducted from my bank account, so my application is processed. I just didn't receive any confirmation letter from them; shouldn't they have sent it?

My main concern is that I'm due to have a holiday abroad in 27/02/2017 and I would need my passport back as I already bought the plane ticket and I booked the hotel room. Is any chance for my application to be finished by then, or at least to get my passport back?

How can I contact them in order to request my passport back?  I thought they make copies of my proof documents and that they send back the originals within 15-20 days, but one month has already passed and nothing has happened.

Comment: Apparently there is a huge backlog in these applications because of huge post-Brexit volume; I do not, however, know the answer to your question.

Comment: It might be helpful for the OP to report the result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are able to have your documents returned to you (emphasis mine).

> **[Get your visa, immigration or citizenship documents back](https://www.gov.uk/visa-documents-returned)**
>
> You can ask for your passport and other documents to be returned if you’ve sent them with your application but need them urgently.
>
> How you do this depends on whether you applied in the UK or not, and what type of application you’ve made.
>
> ***You might have to cancel your application - you’ll be told if you have to do this when you ask for your documents back.***
>
> **If you applied in the UK**
>
> Complete the [online form to get your documents returned](https://eforms.homeoffice.gov.uk/outreach/Return_of_Documents.ofml).
>
> You can’t use this form if you’ve applied for asylum or your application has been refused.
>
> You’ll usually get your documents back within 10 working days.
>
> You can get your documents back quicker if you ask for a [faster decision on your application](https://www.gov.uk/faster-reply-visa-application). This costs £400, in addition to the application fee you’ve already paid.

Comment: Thank you Dorothy for your answer (and editing), I applied in the UK so I could use the online form you have sent it, hopefully it will work successfully, I don't want to cancel my application.

Comment: You're quite welcome; be cautious; as you say, you don't want to cancel the application. Also, you can select the tick mark to accept the answer; thx.